# CollapsingToolbar contentScrim not working

Tags: android, material-design

I am using Coordinator layout within constraint layout and Appbar layout along with CollapsingToolbarLayout, everything is working fine except the attribute contentScrim. It is not working as it is meant to. When I scroll up, the image still shows in the toolbar instead of showing my colorPrimary.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/myCollapse"
                app:title="Fizan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/mToolbar"
                app:contentScrim="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
  android:theme="@style/mToolbar"
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

  <ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 android:src="@drawable/profile"
 app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

 <TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="jdkhasjkdajksdhjkashdjkhsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsahsak"
  android:textSize="35dp" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try  `app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"` instead of  `app:contentScrim="?android:attr/colorPrimary"`

Comment: tried but same result

Comment: Got it, your issue is with `Toolbar` itself, your toolbar has no background color & so it's transparent and showing bg image. Give your toolbar bg color.

Comment: Jeel Vankhede, it does not effect anything, Soon Santos has provided a complete solution. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me. Got from [this](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-android-material-design-course/learn/v4/content) udemy material design course.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.karat.collapsetoolbar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolBarLayout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ocean_menor"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ocean"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>






    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/soonsam"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks..works like charm. Any idea what is the issue with my code?

Comment: The ImageView must come before the Toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to put your put your `<ImageView>` above your `<Toolbar>` like following:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/myCollapse"
            app:title="Fizan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView ....../>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/myCollapse"
                app:title="Fizan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

I hope useful for you :)

Comment: Answer by Soon Santos works for me. Thanks for your interest